# SQL function CONTAINS() does not return expected results?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have a table 'Asset' with a column 'AssetDescription'. Every row of it has some group of words/sentences, seprated by comma.

> row1: - flowers, full color, female, Trend
>
> row2:- baby smelling flowers, heart

Now if I put a search query like:-

```
select * from Asset where contains(AssetDescription,'flower')
```

It returns nothing.

I have one more table 'SearchData' with column 'SearchCol', having similar rows as mentioned above in table 'Asset'.

Now if a put a search query like:-

```
select * from SearchData where contains(SearchCol,'flower')
```

It returns both the rows.

**QUESTION:-**

1. Why first query doesn't return any result, but second one does correctly.
2. If 'Full Text Search' has something to do with 1st ques, than what to do regarding  that. As I'm using SQL server 2000.

***Clearing a comment doubt on my question:-***

1. Table 'SearchData' has more than 100,000 rows and so as the table 'Asset'.
2. Those two tables are NOT identical. But their respective columns has rows that contains some group of words seperated by commas. (So flowers, flower etc etc are in plenty in both of those columns.)

***Screenshot of the Indexes of both the tables (Asset and SearchData):-***
[image]

Comment: What are the column types of the AssertDescription and the SearchCol?

Comment: and if you use contains(..., 'flowers') or contains(..., 'flower*') what are the results?

Comment: and if you use contains(..., 'flowers') or contains(..., 'flower*') what are the results? --> results are some that is NONTHING(zero rows)

Comment: can you try contains(... '"flower*"') with single and double quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it probably has something to do with your full-text index configuration.
Can you post some info on your index and catalog?

Comment: hi, I don't see anything related to full text on the screenshot. You cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on a table that is not full-text indexed.

Comment: I understand ur poitn. But seach query on table 'SearchData' successfully gives results. So how is that possible. Is there a way i could check which table/column has 'fulltextsearch' enabled in it.

Comment: well I supposed there is a full text index on that table, otherwise I would be really surprised.
I dont know on 2000, but on 2005 you can check at "storage" -> "full text catalogs" and then each catalog will show you the tables that uses it

Comment: DIEGO - pls check the updated screen shots. And tell me whats wrong.

Comment: your change tracking is disabled on assets. It means that the index was created but it is not being updated as the table is. You have to repopulate your index. Take a look at this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142575.aspx

Comment: understood. i have enabled those two disabled attributes. And its giving me expected results finally. But Diego, please let me know if enabling those would cause any adverse effect.

Comment: the only effects you would have are related with the population, which is the process of updating your catalog based on your table. 
Glad I helped, please remember to mark as answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the article on [CONTAINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) you will see that when searching for

- contains(AssetDescription,'flower')

'flower' is treated as a *simple term* which

> matches an exact word or phrase

However for

- contains(AssetDescription,'flower*')

'flower' is treated as a *prefix term* which

> specifies a match of words or phrases beginning with the specified
>   text

and will match 'flowers' in your data.

So, are you sure that data in your two tables is the same, or does 'Asset' contain 'flowers' and 'SearchData' contain 'flower'?

Comment: If I understand OP correct, he is saying that searching two identical tables with two identical queries is giving different results. This are two different queries so I doubt it is what OP is after.

Comment: Yes, but if the two tables contain the same data and have the same full text indexs, then the same query must produce the same results.  So either the data is different, the tables are somehow indexed differently or the query is different.

Comment: offcourse but OP has shown the queries so that can be scratched off. We have to take his word on the tables being the same *(I'd rather see it proven somehow)* so all that's left is *somehow indexed differently*.

Comment: OP *should* be showing us the table definitions and indexes. Even better if he could provide a sample script that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @ PHIL and LIEVEN :- please see my explanation on the doubts you guys are having on my question. Hope that helps

Comment: If possible here in this website, I would love to give screenshots of the prob. Its really bothering me.

Comment: @Lieven - let me know, if you want any details about indexing

Comment: @Kings - It is possible to attach an image to your question. Just save it somewhere to disk and use the image upload button when editing your question.

Comment: @Please check the screenhot..or something else is required ?

Answer (score 0):

**GOT THE SOLUTION.**

THANKS TO ALL and especially DIEGO for support.

*To allow the  FULL TEXT SEARCH (FTS) to work properly:-*

1. Enable FTS for the required table.
2. Enable FTS for the required column under that table.
3. Open the properties for the same table and check if attributes 'Full-text change tracking' and  'Full-text update-index' are enabled. If not, enable them.

DONE.
: )

Comment: that's exactly what I said on my comments. You should mark it as answer.